# children in nested grid ignoring parent padding

Tags: html, css, getuikit

here is my code

```
        <div class="uk-container">

            <div class="uk-child-width-1-3@m uk-child-width-1-1@s" uk-grid>

                <div class=" global-border outer-grid">
                    <div class="  main-color" uk-grid>
                        <div class="uk-width-2-5 coine-card bg-yellow  inner-grid" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-width-1-5 bg-yellow-lm  timer coine-card   inner-grid">
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-width-2-5 coine-card bg-yellow  inner-grid" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class=" global-border outer-grid">
                    <div class="  main-color" uk-grid>
                        <div class="uk-width-2-5 coine-card bg-yellow inner-grid " >
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-width-1-5 bg-yellow-lm timer coine-card  inner-grid ">
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-width-2-5 coine-card bg-yellow  inner-grid" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="global-border outer-grid">
                    <div class="bg-yellow" style="height: 200px">
                        some stuff
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

i have a outer grid with 3 columns (they have outer-grid class ) , and inside 2 of these column i have another 3 columns uk-grid (these have inner-grid class) except for one of them which only has a div with `some stuff`  in it !
here is the result

[image]

for some reason the inner grids ignore their parent left padding as result their content seems to be stuck together  ... only the last column which densest have a inner grid seem to respect its parent left padding

why this is happening and how can i solve it  ?

here is jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/pjgr8kb2/

Answer (score 1):

It is the:

```
.uk-grid {
 margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Remove that and you should get the result you want!

NOTE: I also noticed you had a few formatting errors in your **HTML** for example:

```
 <div class="  main-color" uk-grid>
```

Should probably look like this instead:

```
 <div class="main-color uk-grid">
```

Comment: thanx , thats not a formatting errors .. .thats just how uikit framework works 
and i prefer not to touch framework core css

Comment: Would you just be able to add a custom class then and override the framework css where you need it ?

` .tableAdjustment{
   margin-left: 0px !important;
}`

@hretic